# How to except regular expression in gitlab.ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to exclude branches with the names feature/ussues- from some steps. There is a regular expression, but when I set except,rule or only, either the job always was included, or was not included at all.

Initially I tried this using `rules:`:

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ '^feature\.*\/.*    
      when: never
```

I expected this to match on branches like `feature/issues-70`, `feature/issues-771`, etc.

Comment: Please include enough information in your question so that we are able to reproduce the problem. Please include the relevant parts of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` as well as the precise behavior you are seeing and the behavior you are expecting (and why).

Comment: Initially it was like this:
```except:
   - test
   - tags```
Wanted to add:
  ```rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ '^feature\.*\/.*
   when: never```
But it doesn't works
P.S. Sorry for сurve transfers

Comment: Thanks for that information. Please consider editing that into your question with proper formatting -- can you please also give us examples of branch names you want to match that are not matching with that rule?

Comment: feature/issues-70,feature/issues-771,feature/issues-900 etc...

Comment: I've edited your question to include the relevant information. Please feel free to edit further if I've got something wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

The regex rule you used is slightly off. First, you need surrounding `/` for the regex pattern. Second, the `\.` in the pattern will mean to match a literal `.` character, which is not what you want, based on the branch names you expect to match. Lastly, you need a matching rule for the job to be created at all (the default case when your rule doesn't match).

This should match all the example branch names you provided:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never  # same as except: - tags
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "test"
    when: never  # same as except: - test
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\/.*/
    when: never
  - when: on_success # the default when the first rule doesn't match
```

Comment: I need to except tags and test branch too in this stage.How i can do this?

Comment: @HavyZail I edited the answer to add those conditions.